# Proving that $|A_n| = n!/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I can't figure out why we need $\phi$ to be bijective in order to conclude $|A_n| = |S_n| - |A_n|$, could someone please explain how this works?

Comment: If you have a bijection between two sets $X,Y$, you know the two sets have equally many elements. If you have just any map, you cannot conclude anything about the sizes.